# HTML (or jQuery): Select either one or both checkboxes (or radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have two checkboxes in HTML which are both selected by default. Users can de-select them.

Now, I would like to have at least one of the two checkboxes checked constantly. That is, users can either have both of them checked, or only one of them, but they should not be able to de-select both.

(Background information: They are connected to a hide/show-jQuery-toggle, and deselecting both would make the whole page empty.)

Do you know how to do this (with either checkboxes or radio buttons - or something else)? I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: On click, check to see if the checkbox is the only one checked.  If it is, cancel the event.

Comment: You should use radio buttons with 3 options; A, B, Both.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" data-bind="div1" name="radioGroup" value="both" class="radioGroup">
  <input type="radio" data-bind="div2" name="radioGroup" value="Option 1" class="radioGroup">
  <input type="radio" data-bind="div3" name="radioGroup" value="Option 2" class="radioGroup">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName(`radioGroup`);

[...radioButtons].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener(event => {
     const boundElement = event.target.dataset.bind;
     classOfToggle.forEach(element => {
         element.id === boundElement 
           ? element.style.display = `block` 
           : element.style.display = `none`;
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said using jQuery:

Essentially we just add an event listener, and if there are no boxes checked, we prevent the last box from being unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="at-least-one">
<input type="checkbox" class="at-least-one">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".at-least-one", function(evt) {
  // This is technically run after the checked value changes, so we're checking
  //   if there is no more boxes checked after we uncheck this one. If there is
  //   no more, then prevent the event, setting the box back to checked.
  if ($(".at-least-one:checked").length == 0) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    return false
  }
})  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `click` event listener to both of them and `return false` if the number of checked checkboxes is a falsey value (`0`).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>One checkbox must always be checked</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkone" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkone" checked>
<script>
$('input[name=checkone]').click(function(e){
  if(!$('input[name=checkone]:checked').length){
   return false;
  }
});
</script>
```